# How to set List<List<double>> (Or two dimensional array) as data source to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, matrix, datasource

I have `List<List<double>>` with values and wpf datagrid.
How can I set this as dataSource to my dataGrid?

I have tried following:

```
public class DataContainer
{
    public List<List<double>> List { get; set; }
    public List<string> Headers { get; set; }
}

private void InitializeGrid(DataContainer container)
{
    var table = new DataTable();

    foreach (var header in container.Headers)
    {
       dataGrid1.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn(){Header = header});
       table.Columns.Add(header);
    }
    foreach (var lst in container.List)
    {
       var dr = table.NewRow();

       var array = (from o in lst
                    select (object)o).ToArray();

       dr.ItemArray = array;

       table.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    foreach (var row in table.Rows)
    {
        dataGrid1.Items.Add(row);
    }

   // dataGrid1.ItemsSource = table.Rows;
}
```

And this only add headers and empty rows.

Comment: You are adding a header to the column but you are not binding any content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go two directions but you need to pick one.

One:

Create the DataTable (not the columns).  Use the headers to name the columns in the DataTable.  Bind the DataTable with autogenerate columns.

Two:

Do NOT create the DataTable.  Bind to List (using List as a property name is a bad practice and confusing).  Then you you bind the column content to something like List[0],  List[1].  I am not sure what the syntax is as I have done List where MyClass has a public List MyRows and then the syntax for the content binding is MyRows[0], MyRows[1] ....